# RAX stores value or address of the arithmetic and logical solution?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I was reading,

[image]

Now I wanted to know if it stores the address of the results or the results themselves(values)?

Thankyou.

Comment: In most texts it's pretty clear. This text is unclear both in meaning and visually.

Answer (score 1):

RAX stores the values for the results of mathematical calculations.